# Is there a function or method to perform something like std::promise in glib

Tags: gstreamer, glib

My question is as above. Is there some methods to perform something similar to std::promise(like performing some action x time later) using glib?

Or is there some timer probe in glib... like putting a delay for like some specific amount of time

Need to do repetitive action in gstreamer ie attach to a branch and detach a branch at regular interval (repetitively after starting it up using g_source_set_callback)

Regards

Comment: `g_timeout_add()`

Comment: Philip's comment is what you're looking for. Just make sure to return G_SOURCE_CONTINUE (which is the same as TRUE) from within your callback as long as you expect the callback to keep being called periodically

Comment: @nieldsg can you add g_timeout_add in a loop created by g_source_set_callback()?